# Numbering claims

Tags: numbering

I would like to have the claims in the proof of a given theorem or proposition numbered independently from those in a different theorem or proposition.  This question has already been asked here: [ntheorem: numbering of claim and its proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248757/ntheorem-numbering-of-claim-and-its-proof/354361#354361).
However, I must be doing something wrong as it does not work for me.  Typing

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition} \newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}

\begin{document}

\section{blah}

\begin{thm} 
\begin{claim} 
\end{claim} 
\end{thm}

\begin{prop} 
\begin{claim} 
\end{claim} 
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

does not number claims within the theorem or proposition they refer to but sequentially to them. I tried also with `\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}`, but it gives me an error:

> (Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're using the `amsart` class which defines many features `ntheorem` wants to provide as well -- and this must conflict. It is stated in the documentation of `ntheorem`, that `amsthm` shouldn't be  used with `ntheorem`, the same is true for `amsart`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting what you have asked for: claims numbered in the same sequence as theorems and propositions.  If you want claims to be numbered *within* them, instead, you must replace

```
\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}
```

with

```
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[thm]
```

Here’s a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % unrelated to your question, but I'd recommend it

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[thm]

\begin{document}

\section{Blah}

\begin{thm}
    Statement of theorem.
    \begin{claim}
        Statement of claim.
    \end{claim}
    More text.
    \begin{claim}
        Statement of another claim.
    \end{claim}
    End of theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
    Statement of proposition.
    \begin{claim} 
        Statement of claim.
    \end{claim} 
    More text.
    \begin{claim}
        Statement of another claim.
    \end{claim}
    End of proposition.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

And here’s the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Great!  But what is the difference between                 \newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}   and                      \newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[thm]?  I mean, in general.

Comment: Great, thanks!  But what is the difference between \newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}

Comment: @AlessandraIozzi: It’s explained in the manual of the `amsthm` package (_Using the `amsthm` Package_), section 3 (pp. 5–7).  You should be able to display that document by opening a terminal emulator window and typing the command `texdoc amsthm`.